# What is JSON data for key and value property in formio select component

Tags: angular, typescript, formio

I'm adding static values through JSON on Select Component.Here are some properties  ..

```
 components: {
     address: {
         title: 'Address',
         key: 'address',
         icon: 'fa fa-th-list',
         schema: {
             label: 'Address',
             type: 'select',
             placeholder: 'Select Address',
             key: 'address', 
             dataPath:'hello',
             data:{
                 url: https://cdn.rawgit.com/mshafrir/2646763/raw/states_titlecase.json',
             },
             limit: 100,
             dataSrc: 'url',
         }
     }
 }
```

like the same I have to define key and value property here, is there any property names for that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I created one custom formio select component,and i have to give some predifined data that user cannot change and it for read only.For this i had given some fields like 'dataPath' , dataSrc.Same this in the formio select component there is one field called key and value in data property,i have to set that fields also predifined and when i open formio and if i go to select component  there must be predefined data will present like   placeholder-Select Address , limit - 100 , dataPath-hello

Answer (score 0):

yes add this at the same level than label/type/key etc:

```
"data": {
  "values": [
    {
      "label": "label",
      "value": "the value
    },
    ...
  ]
},
```